# Serial communication read not working at all time

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I am writing a c++ application for half duplex communication to download data from a device. Following is the class i am using for serial communication.

```
class CSerialCommHelper 
{
    HANDLE m_pPortHandle;           //Handle to the COM port
    HANDLE m_hReadThread;           //Handle to the Read thread
    HANDLE m_hPortMutex;            //Handle to Port Mutex
    std::wstring m_strPortName;     //Portname
    COMMTIMEOUTS m_CommTimeouts;    //Communication Timeout Structure
    _DCB dcb;                       //Device Control Block
    DWORD m_dwThreadID;             //Thread ID
    string m_strBuffer;

public:
    CSerialCommHelper();
    HRESULT Open();
    HRESULT ConfigPort();
    static void * ReadThread(void *);
    HRESULT Write(const unsigned char *,DWORD);
    string GetFrameFromBuffer();
    HRESULT Close();
    ~CSerialCommHelper(void);
};
```

ReadThread and Write function is as follows :

```
  void * CSerialCommHelper::ReadThread(void * pObj)
  {
    CSerialCommHelper *pCSerialCommHelper =(CSerialCommHelper *)pObj; 
    DWORD dwBytesTransferred =0;
    DWORD byte=0;;

    while (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        pCSerialCommHelper->m_strBuffer.clear();
        pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize=0;

        WaitForSingleObject(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex,INFINITE);

        do
        {
            dwBytesTransferred = 0;


            ReadFile (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle,&byte,1,&dwBytesTransferred,NULL);
            if (dwBytesTransferred == 1)
            {
                pCSerialCommHelper->m_strBuffer.push_back((char)byte);
                pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize++;
                continue;
            }


        }
        while ((dwBytesTransferred == 1) && (pCSerialCommHelper->m_pPortHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE));


            ReleaseMutex(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex);
            Sleep(2);


    }
    ExitThread(0);


    return 0;
```

}

Write function waits for readthread to release mutex and writes to data to port .
GetFrameFromBuffer will be called from application which uses the SerialCommhelper
and it returns the m_strBuffer string .

My problem is whenever i am trying to  download huge amount of data.
I am losing some data frames . 
I am getting response from device in between .0468 to .1716 secs.

After analysing different error scenarios i came to know that is not problem with time as other frames are getting downloaded at the same time interval.

Function which is calling getframebuffer is  continuosly calling it until is gets a filled string.

Comment: one passing note, maybe unrelated. When you cast the argument like that you are assuming that whatever function started the thread (and its data) will have a life expectancy longer than the thread. It is safer not to assume such a thing, instead keep a local copy of the argument. But maybe you thought about already and have some global instance that you are passing

Comment: I worked on a project once that used a very similar method to read serial data from projectors, which also failed intermittently. Unfortunately, we never knew why exactly, but changing the reading method to use [Completion Routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) solved the problem.

Comment: That Sleep() call is *very* suspect, remove it and address the real problem.  The m_hPortMutex is very creepy as well, nothing good ever happens when multiple threads call ReadFile and they each get a sliver of data.  You have no hope of gluing that back together again accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like these two statements should not be in your outer `while` loop:

```
    pCSerialCommHelper->m_strBuffer.clear();
    pCSerialCommHelper->m_usBufSize=0;
```

Your inner while loop reads bytes as long as they're immediately available, and the outer loop does a `Sleep(2)` the moment the inner loop doesn't give you a byte.

If you're waiting until an entire packet is available, it seems like you should keep looping until you get all the bytes, without clearing partway through the process.

I don't really know the `ReadFile` API, but I'm guessing that `ReadFile` might return 0 if there's no bytes immediately available, or at least available by whatever timeout you specified when opening the serial device.

Answer (score 2):

```
        ReleaseMutex(pCSerialCommHelper->m_hPortMutex);
        Sleep(2);
```

That Sleep() call is hiding the real problem.  It is **never** correct in threaded code, always a band-aid for a timing bug.

You certainly seem to have one, that m_hPortMutex spells doom as well.  If you do in fact have multiple threads trying to read from the serial port then they are going to start fighting over that mutex.  The outcome will be very poor, each thread will get a handful of bytes from the port.  But clearly you want to read a *frame* of data.  There is zero hope that you can glue the handfuls of bytes that each thread gets back together into a frame, you've lost their sequence.  So sleeping for a while *seemed* like a workaround, it inject delays that can give you a better shot at reading a frame.  Usually, not always.  You also wrote it in the wrong place.

This code is just broken.  Delete the Sleep().  Do *not* exit the loop until you've read the entire frame.

Comment: Only  one ReadThread is being used to read an entire frame from one port.
Sleep(2) function ensures that Write() will be able acquire Port mutex so that it can write commands to Port.
I tried first without Sleep(2) it ended with a deadlock as Readthread acquires the released mutex immediately. So Write function will fail.

Comment: Using Sleep() to solve a deadlock problem is even worse, that's guaranteed to fail to work sooner or later.  A serial port supports reading and writing at the same time, no need for a mutex.  A core problem is that your code does not in fact do anything to ensure an entire frame is received.  You quit when there are no more bytes to read, that's wrong.  Serial ports are very slow.

Comment: +1, 'Only one ReadThread is being used' - then you don't need the mutex at all. The tx and rx paths are independent and can be handled by two threads without locking.  I can't see the write call?  Also, it looks like you are continually creating, terminating and destroying threads for half-duplex comms.  You should only need one thread with a loop in it: 'while(true){read();write()};'.  Oh, and yes, as the others have said, get rid of the sleep call.